# A Taylor–Lagrange formula question.

Tags: calculus

If I expand 
$$\cosh(x) = 1 +\frac{x^2}{2} + \cosh(c_1)\frac{x^4}{24}$$

Where $c_1$ is some point between 0 and x.

If I expand 
$$\sinh(x) = x +\frac{x^3}{6} + \sinh(c_2)\frac{x^5}{120}$$

Where $c_2$ is some point between 0 and x.

I know that we can never know these numbers exactly, but can we compare them? Is there any way to compare $c_1$ with $c_2$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, I will try to rewrite it right now.

Answer (score 1):

First note that in the formula for $Sinh(x)$, this is $Cosh(c_2)$ instead of $Sinh(c_2)$.

You have for $x>0$:

$$Cosh(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}Cosh(c_1)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^6}{30\times 24}Cosh(d_1)$$
with $d_1\in (0,x)$.

Hence:

$$Cosh(c_1)=1+\frac{x^{2}}{30}Cosh(d_1)$$
As $c_1,d_1$ $\to 0$ if $x \to 0$ (and they are not $0$), we get $\displaystyle Cosh(c_1)-1\sim \frac{c_1^2}{2}\sim \frac{x^2}{30}$.
In the same way:
$$Cosh(c_2)=1+\frac{x^{2}}{42}Cosh(d_2)$$
and hence $\displaystyle Cosh(c_2)-1\sim \frac{c_2^2}{2}\sim \frac{x^2}{42}$.

Hence we get that $\displaystyle \frac{c_2}{c_1}\to \sqrt{\frac{5}{7}}$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: This was extremely extremely helpful. But can I just get this right, you are saying that a taylor expansion of Sinh(x), would be:

Sinh(x)=x+x^3/6+Cosh(x)x^4/120 ? Where may I confirm this?

Comment: No, I say that the  derivative of order 5 of Sinh(x) is Cosh(x); hence  the term $Sinh(c_2)\frac{x^5}{5!}$ must be replaced by $Cosh(c_2)\frac{x^5}{5!}$

Comment: Oh you are right, thank you sir :).